# How to display one iframe in a 3D scene in stereo vr mode? Three.js

Tags: canvas, three.js, webvr

How can I correctly display an iframe in a 3D scene in stereoscopic mode? The iframe will contain a game with canvas. I am using three.js
Found a working example, but it loads 2 different iframes and the games work independently. That is, for each eye its own independent iframe works - http://joxi.ru/E2pXlBDcaMEdl2
Here is an example - http://www.carlostoxtli.com/iframe-vr-threejs-webgl-css3d/#vr You must insert a link.

I tried to solve the problem with another way. Having added the game, I transferred the current screenshot of the canvas (base64 for example) from the iframe through the PostMessage, displayed it in the intermediate canvas on the page and transferred this canvas as a texture to three.js. The circuit works but is very resource intensive.
 and I need to refine every game that ties my hands tightly. http://joxi.ru/4Akad8DSXEpMDm

Tell me please, maybe there is a simple solution for displaying one iframe in VR stereo mode?

Comment: AFAICT the answer is "no, there is no way to display an iframe in VR stereo mode" currently.

Comment: sure, it's possible .... See WebXR ... and aframe.io for sure